# Is it possible to say "I will tell you before it will be sold out"?

Tags: tense

"I will let you know before it sells out" is correct English but can we say "before it will be sold out". I don't think so because when we say this sentence we are not waiting for a date as in " I will tell you when it will be out" the person  who says this is thinking of a date (it will be out on Monday, tomorrow ....)
Am I right in thinking that

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't say "before it will be".  Think of it this way: "it will be X" means "X is in the future".  What does it mean to say "*before* X is in the future"?  That doesn't make any sense.  How can something be before that?

Comment: Yes, you analysis agrees with the answer in the duplicate.